# VirtualBox performance problems

Tags: windows, virtualbox, performance

I have a Dell Notebook with reasonably good hardware: a Core i7 proccessor, 16gb of RAM memory, 2gb of VRAM and some space on SSD to store the OS. Even though I have those settings, I can't manage to get a good performance on my Windows 8.1 on Virtual Machine. I gave it 8gb of RAM, 256gb of VRAM and accelerated 2d and 3d, but I still can't manage to get good performance. Could you guys help me? :)

Comment: Have you installed guest additions? [Chapter 4. Guest Additions](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html)

Comment: Question is not well put.  Windows is generally slow, it will always be slower than that in a VM. I have had Win 7 and Win 10 VMs running and I'd estimate that using Windows Explorer or MS Excel takes about 20% longer inside the VM.  Also, you don't tell us what "fast" is, or what particular action is not fast.

Comment: Are all cores enabled on VM? Is CPU limit set to 100%?

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce your VM RAM to 2048, 128K VRAM, and set your VM CPU count = 2. That should make it fly. Cheers, Al